# Is there a way to generate batch labels in a column in excel

Tags: excel

I have a report that I run that requires separation of batches so that I can process it efficiently. The easiest way to do this is to add a column in excel with a simple numerical label based on the number  batch. So the column would have the number 1 for thirty rows, then the number 2, and so on. This would also be dependent on a value in another column to filter the batches for specific kinds of data. Is there any way to automate this with a formula or macro? I have only a little excel experience using mainly vlookup functions and simple arithmetic and statistical formulas.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For a formula, you can use:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/30,0)+1
```